# In Azure DevOps Pipelines. How do you choose an alternate GitHub branch?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

B"H

Simply. I'd like to build the code in a branch of my GitHub repo that is not master.
I don't see any option to do that.
It lets you choose which repo you want to checkout as the first step in a pipeline, but not which branch.

I see that once you've created the pipeline. There is a file `azure-pipelines.yml` which has a line called trigger.
However

1. It's not only which branch I want to trigger the build. It's also that I want use the code from the second branch for this build
2. It does not give you the option to save azure-pipelines.yml in any branch other than master (or one that it will create right then for you **from master**)
3. Changing the branch listed under trigger doesn't actually work. (probably because of the first two issues). It still only triggers if check into master

So how would I choose an alternate branch.
Thank you.

Comment: i.e. I need to create a build pipline for a feature branch to build it and push it to staging for QA to see and test before I merge into master

Answer (score 3):

1,For classic view pipeline. Go to your pipeline, click **edit** to edit your pipeline, In  **tasks** page,click **Get sources**, and choose default branch to build, as shown in below pic.
[image]

2,For yaml pipeline, go to your pipeline, click the **eclipse** the 3 dots in the upper right corner, choose **triggers**, go to **YAML** page as shown in below pic

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the YAML Editor:

1. Go to Options (3 dots in the upper right corner)
2. Triggers
3. YAML
4. Click on "Get Sources"
5. Select your default branch under "Default branch for manual and scheduled builds"

Additonally if you queue the build manually you can edit the source branch under "Branch/tag"

Comment: Trying. Still not getting it to work.
Right now I'm just using creating the pipelines from the web applications management blade (where you do have the option for a branch) or I'm using the old (classic) interface for pipelines.

Comment: Check @Levi Lu-MSFT comment with a visual guide. That's the way to go. If it is still not working check if you saved your changes or post your logs.

Answer (score 0):

Go to GitHub to your branch, create a new file with the name `azure-pipelines.yml`, paste the yaml of your pipeline and in the trigger put the branch name.

For example, I created the file in my `uwp-controls` branch:

[image]

This is the content:

```
trigger:
- uwp-controls

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

After the commit a new pipeline created for the `uwp-controls` branch:

[image]